# Error (9322): No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, foundry

Here is the file which i try to run test through foundry.

```
//Imports
import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Portal} from "../src/Portal.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {StdCheatsSafe} from "forge-std/StdCheats.sol" ;



 function testDust() public {

        IERC20 LocalHLP = IERC20(0x4307fbDCD9Ec7AEA5a1c2958deCaa6f316952bAb);


        address bob = makeAddr("bob");
        deal(LocalHLP , bob , 10000e18 ,);
        portal.contributeFunding(1000e18);

        address alice = makeAddr("alice");
        deal(IERC20(LocalHLP) , address(alice) , 1000000e18);
        portal.contributeFunding(10000e18);

        address Gary = makeAddr("Gary");
        deal(LocalHLP , Gary , 100000e18 );
        portal.contributeFunding(10000e18);

        address ajax = makeAddr("ajax");
        deal(LocalHLP , ajax , 10000e18);
        portal.contributeFunding(1000e18);
}
```

**Error**

```
 forge build                                                                                          1 ⨯ 1 ⚙
[⠒] Compiling...
[⠰] Compiling 49 files with 0.8.20
[⠔] Solc 0.8.20 finished in 1.23s
Error: 
Compiler run failed:
Error (9322): No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
  --> test/DustCheck.t.sol:38:9:
   |
38 |         deal(LocalHLP , bob , 10000e18 ,true );
   |         ^^^^
```

I tried many ways but no use, is there any solution for this or something to change in test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use `vm.deal()`
2. Also try put the `function testDust() public` in `contract ContractTest is Test {}`
3. `deal(address(LocalHLP) , bob , 10000e18 ,);`

Comment: First one worked. But it's giving another error. ```Wrong argument count for function call: 3 arguments given but expected 2.
  --> test/DustCheck.t.sol:38:9:
   |
38 |         vm.deal(address(LocalHLP) , bob , 10000e18);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ```

Comment: Thanks for answer 1 and 3 worked. but 3. should be like this ``` deal(address(LocalHLP) , bob , 10000e18 );
```